# ASP.NET: Constructing bidimensional array and sending it to the View

Tags: asp.net, arrays, asp.net-mvc, multidimensional-array, asp.net-core

**About the project:**

I'm working on a project for slot machines.

In my model, I have a class (`Machine`) where I storage the slow changing properties such as `id`, `inventory_code`, `machine_type`, etc.

I also keep a fact table (`Machine_Facts`) where I storage the incomes these machines generated. This fact table contains the last date the machine where open to collect the coins from it (`last_date`). It also contains other properties such as `inventory_code`.

**Problem**

I have a problem working with the view. I would like to present a view like this:

[image]

This is the view where we would access each slot machine and register how much cash we took out of each machine.

This view can be made calling the information of the `Machine` class to the view mostly, except for the `Fecha` value (`last_date` property) since this property is in the fact table.

How can I search inside the fact table for a list of `inventory_code` and `last_date`, and bring the most recent date (this would be a 2 dimensional array).

After that I'm thinking of passing both the `Machine` class and the array to the `View` using a ViewModel.

Would this be a correct approach to the problem? Any other suggestions?

**Data so far:**

*Models:*

*ViewModel*

```
namespace Application.Models.ApplicationviewModels
{
    public class IncomeIndexData
    {
        public int fact_id { get; set; }
        /*Other properties related to the income*/
        //This list contains most of the properties of the machine
        public List<Machine> MachinesL { get; set; }

    }

    public class MachineLastDate
    {
        public string machine_cod { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime last_date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*Machine*

```
namespace Application.Models
{
    public class Machine
    {
        [Key]
        public int machine_id { get; set; }
        /*Other machine properties*/
        public string inventory_code { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Machine_Fact> Machine_Facts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*Fact*

```
public class Machine_Facts
{
    [Key]
    public int fact_id { get; set; }
    /*Other properties*/
    //Foreign Keys
    [ForeignKey("machine_id")]
    public virtual Machine Machines{ get; set; }

    public int machine_id { get; set; }
 }
```

*Controller:*

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var machines = await _context.Machines.Where(t => t.Machines.mac_liquidador == User.Identity.Name).ToListAsync();

        var fact_machine_last_liq = await _context.FactIncome.Select(??).ToListAsync();
        IncomeIndexData Income = new IncomeIndexData()
        {
            MachinesL = machines,
            MachineLastDate = fact_machine_last_liq
        };

        return View(Income);
    }
```

*View:*

```
            <table style="width:100%;" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td><div>Familia</div></td>
                        <td><div>Modelo</div></td>
                        <td><div>Código</div></td>
                        <td><div>Contador</div></td>
                        <td><div>Última Liquidación</div></td>
                        <td><div>Liquidar</div></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach (var item in Model.ContadoresL)
                {
                @if (item.tienda_nombre == tienda)
                {

                    <tbody>
                        @if (item.machine_active != 0)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@item.mac_familia_desc</td>
                                <td>@item.mac_descrip</td>
                                <td>@item.mac_comercial_cod</td>
                                <td>@item.mac_internal_cod</td>
                                <td>Fecha</td>
                                //search the internal_cod in the bidimensional array and bring the date
                                //@foreach (var date in Model.MachineLastDate){
                                  if(item.mac_internal_cod == date.machine_code){<td>@date.lastdate</td>}
                                  }
                                //
                                <td colspan="14" align="right">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Liquidar" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                }
                }
            </table>
```

Comment: What is the FK relationship between `Machine` and `Machine_Facts`? You can just use a `join` statement and get the last date for each `Machine`

Comment: @StephenMuecke hello, question updated. They have a one to many relationship thru machine_id (autogenerated), however, the durable key is `inventory_code`. What kind of object could I sent to the view that contains the result of the join? I'm thinking it would be the `machine` list enriched with a new column with the `date`?

Comment: I am confused by your names - is `HechosLiquidador` the same as `Machine_Facts` and what you have also referred to as `Fact`? And does `Machine` contain a `virtual ICollection<HechosLiquidador>` property?

Comment: @StephenMuecke My bad, Yes, `hechosliquidador` was the same as `machine_facts` (question updated so it only shows `machine_facts`. Yes, Machine does containt a collection of `machine_facts`. `facts` table would be the table that records the profits made from each machine. This table would have several records of these profits for each machine each month.

Comment: Then you should have a view model (say `MachineVM`) that contains the properties of `Machine` that you need plus a `DateTime LastDate` property and you query would be something like `_context.Machines.Where(...).Include(x => x.MachineFacts)..AsEnumerable().Select(x => new MachineVM { ID = x.machine_id, ....., LastDate = x.MachineFacts.Last().last_date });` (I'll see if I can find you a link with more detail shortly)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hello, I don't know if I'm doing this correctly. I'm getting a response from the view saying that the sequence contains no elements :( I'll keep exploring but I have the feeling this is the correct approach.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I mean, this part of the code: `Select(x => new MachineVM {}` is it populating the ViewModel? With the `Select` ?

Comment: Yes, the `.Select(...)` will initialize and populate an instance of `MachineVM` for each item returned by your query, and the result will be `IEnmerable<MachineVM>`. The error is thrown because your query returns no matching records and because you call `.Last()`. If there is a risk that no records match you query, then you will need to modify it slightly. But suggest you ask a new question with the relevant models and code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Create a ViewModel with the properties you Need. Try not to do it in the view. Create a separate method and process it. Try this below with appropriate properties

```
 public class IncomeIndexDataViewModel
 {
      public string mac_familia_desc { get; set; }
      public string mac_descrip { get; set; }
      public string mac_comercial_cod { get; set; }
      public string mac_internal_cod { get; set; }
      public DateTime Codigo { get; set; }
 }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var machines = await _context.Machines.Where(t => t.Machines.mac_liquidador == User.Identity.Name).ToListAsync();

        var fact_machine_last_liq = await _context.FactIncome.Select(??).ToListAsync();

        var data = transform(machines,fact_machine_last_liq);
        return View(data);
    }

    private  List<IncomeIndexDataViewModel> transform(List<Machines> machines, List<FactIncome> fact_machine_last_date )
    {
        var results = new List<IncomeIndexDataViewModel>();
        foreach (var item in machines)
        {
            results.Add(new IncomeIndexDataViewModel{
                mac_familia_desc = item.mac_familia_desc
                mac_descrip = item.mac_descrip
                mac_comercial_cod = item.mac_comercial_cod
                mac_internal_cod = item.mac_internal_cod
                Codigo = fact_machine_last_date.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.mac_internal_cod==item.machine_code)
            });
        }
        return results;
    }
```

### In View

```html
@ { var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, rowsPerPage: 10); }
<div id="grid">
  @grid.GetHtml( tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-sm", mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, firstText: "
  << First ",  
            previousText: "< Prev ",  
            nextText: "Next>", lastText: "Last >>", //add next or prev link in webgrid columns: grid.Columns( grid.Column("mac_familia_desc"), grid.Column("mac_descrip"), grid.Column("mac_comercial_cod") grid.Column("mac_internal_cod") grid.Column("Codigo") ) )
</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't find this function (Transform): `var data = transform(machines,fact_machine_last_liq);`

Comment: I meant you to write a transform method of your own to do the job.